# Magento 2 : I Can get Collection from database but cannot save data in database

Tags: magento2, module, database

I have a custom table in which I want to save data.
I tried below different methods to save data in table.But cannot get success.
Please check below methods :

Method 1 :

```
$model = $this->_objectManager->create('Namesapce\Modulename\Model\Test\Product');
$model->setRowId(1);
$model->setProductId(2048);
$model->save();
```

Method 2 :

```
$model = $this->_objectManager->create('Namesapce\Modulename\Model\Test\Product');
$data = ['row_id' => 1, 'product_id' => '2048'] ;
$model->setData($data);
$model->save();
```

For testing purpose I have manually insert data in table and then try to getcollection.

Strange thing is I can sucessfully get collection of data from table.but can not save. I also put above code in try catch but it always going in try. Not in catch.

Please take me out from this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: we can get more close to your issue if we could see full code of your save controller & Model Collection

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using a resource model ModelFactory, rather than trying to create through the object manager.

Answer (score 0):

Please **Flush magento cache** and try to save again if it's not work, then
See your log folder and do some debugging in your module:

Comment: I tried to flush magento cache and also check log folder.But no error is found.

Answer (score 0):

```
$model = $this->_objectManager->create('Namesapce\Modulename\Model\Test\Product')->getCollection();
$model->setRowId(1);
$model->setProductId(2048);
$model->save();
```

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more on what your code example is doing and how it will solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had faced same problem when working on Magento2 CRUD. Never use Primary Key with model save() method.

Definately row_id will be primary key.

## How to check we created the correct model , resource & collection class in magento.

#### In magento2 $this->_objectManager interface use for creating the model object.

$subscription = $this->_objectManager->create('path-to-model class');

Example: Abc\Hello\Model\Subscription.

Use get_class($subscription) method. This will show the full class path.